# Expand/Collapse all with Nested Table - jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am using datatables plugin. I would like to ask, is there any way to expand/collapse all rows of the nested table. I tried to implement this below, but it doesn't work. I would like to expand/collapse rows like this example
https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/#regular.
Please help thanks

```js
  function fnFormatDetails(table_id, html) {

      var sOut = "<table id=\"exampleTable_" + table_id + "\">";

      sOut += html;
      sOut += "</table>";
      return sOut;
  }
  var iTableCounter = 1;
  var oTable;
  var oInnerTable;
  var TableHtml;

  //Run On HTML Build
  $(document).ready(function () {

      TableHtml = $('#exampleTable_2').html();

      //Insert a 'details' column to the table
      var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
      var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');

      nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">';
      nCloneTd.className = "center";
      $('#exampleTable thead tr').each(function () {
          this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
      });

      $('#exampleTable tbody tr').each(function () {
          this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
      });

      //Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
      var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
              'bJQueryUI': true,

              'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
              'aoColumnDefs': [{
                      'bSortable': false,
                      'class': 'details-control',
                      'aTargets': [0]
                  }
              ],
              'aaSorting': [[1, 'asc']]
          });

      /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
       * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
       * rather it is done here
       */
      $('#exampleTable tbody tr img').on('click', function () {
          var nTr = $(this).closest('tr');

          if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {

              /* This row is already open - close it */
              this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
              oTable.fnClose(nTr);
          } else {
              /* Open this row */
              this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
              oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details-control');
              oInnerTable = $('#exampleTable_' + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                      'bJQueryUI': true,
                      'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
                  });
              iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;

          }

          $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function () {
              // Enumerate all rows
              oTable.rows().every(function () {
                  // If row has details collapsed
                  if (!this.oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                      /* Open this row */
                      this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
                      this.oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details-control');
                      this.oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                              'bJQueryUI': true,
                              'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
                          });
                      iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
                  }
              });
          });

          // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
          $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function () {
              // Enumerate all rows
              oTable.rows().every(function () {
                  // If row has details expanded
                  if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {

                      /* This row is already open - close it */
                      this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
                      oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                  }
              });
          });
          $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function () {
              // Enumerate all rows
              oTable.rows().every(function () {
                  // If row has details collapsed
                  if (!this.oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                      /* Open this row */
                      this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
                      this.oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details-control');
                      this.oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                              'bJQueryUI': true,
                              'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
                          });
                      iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
                  }
              });
          });

          // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
          $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function () {
              // Enumerate all rows
              oTable.rows().every(function () {
                  // If row has details expanded
                  if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {

                      /* This row is already open - close it */
                      this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
                      oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  });
```

```css
td.details-control {
        background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    tr.shown td.details-control {
        background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
```

```html
 <html>
     <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Col reorder with resize-->  
        <script src="colreorderwithresize.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>     
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
     </head>

    <body>
    <button id="btn-show-all-children" type="button">Expand All</button>
     <button id="btn-show-all-children" type="button">Collapse All</button>
    <table id="exampleTable">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Savings</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
          <td>2012</td>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2012</td>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>  
         <div style="display:none">
    <table id="exampleTable_2" class="display select" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th> 
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th> 
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Extn.</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger</td>
          <td>Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
          <td>5421</td>
          <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett</td>
          <td>Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
          <td>8422</td>
          <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>  
    </table>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PROBLEM

There are too many issues with the code to list them all. For example:

- Multiple versions of jQuery DataTables included - 1.9 and 1.10
- Multiple versions of jQuery included: 1.11 and 3.5
- DataTables 1.10 API method such as `rows()` are called on DataTables 1.9 instance, see [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more details.
- Event handlers are assigned multiple times in incorrect places.

#### SOLUTION

Please see below the corrected code and adjust to the libraries that you're using.

```js
function fnFormatDetails(table_id, html) {

      var sOut = "<table id=\"exampleTable_" + table_id + "\">";

      sOut += html;
      sOut += "</table>";
      return sOut;
  }
  var iTableCounter = 1;
  var oTable;
  var oInnerTable;
  var TableHtml;

  //Run On HTML Build
  $(document).ready(function () {

      TableHtml = $('#exampleTable_2').html();

      //Insert a 'details' column to the table
      var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
      var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');

      $('#exampleTable thead tr').each(function () {
          this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
      });

      //Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
      var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
              'bJQueryUI': true,

              'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
              'aoColumnDefs': [{
                      'bSortable': false,
                      'class': 'details-control',
                      'aTargets': [0]
                  }
              ],
              'aaSorting': [[1, 'asc']]
          });

      /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
       * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
       * rather it is done here
       */
      $('#exampleTable tbody tr td.details-control').on('click', function () {
          var nTr = $(this).closest('tr');

          if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {

              oTable.fnClose(nTr);
          } else {
              oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details-control');
              oInnerTable = $('#exampleTable_' + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                      'bJQueryUI': true,
                      'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
                  });
              iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;

          }
      });
      

      // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
      $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function () {
          // Enumerate all rows
          oTable.$('tr').each(function(index, nTr){              
              // If row has details expanded
              if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                  oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                  $(nTr).removeClass('shown');
              }
          });
      });

      $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function () {
          // Enumerate all rows              
          oTable.$('tr').each(function(index, nTr){
              // If row has details collapsed
              if (!oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
                  /* Open this row */
                  oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, TableHtml), 'details-control');
                  $(nTr).addClass('shown');
              }
          });
      });      
  });
```

```css
td.details-control {
        background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    tr.shown td.details-control {
        background: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/DataTables/DataTables/6c7ada53ebc228ea9bc28b1b216e793b1825d188/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
```

```html
<html>
     <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.21/datatables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Col reorder with resize-->  
        <script src="colreorderwithresize.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.21/datatables.min.js"></script>  
     </head>

    <body>
    <button id="btn-show-all-children" type="button">Expand All</button>
     <button id="btn-hide-all-children" type="button">Collapse All</button>
    <table id="exampleTable" class="display">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Savings</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>2012</td>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>2012</td>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>  
         <div style="display:none">
    <table id="exampleTable_2" class="display select" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th> 
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th> 
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Extn.</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger</td>
          <td>Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
          <td>5421</td>
          <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett</td>
          <td>Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
          <td>8422</td>
          <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>  
    </table>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

#### LINK

Please see [jQuery DataTables: How to expand/collapse all child rows](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/) for more information and examples.